# Pop-up changing view in background

Tags: asp.net, html, css, error-handling

I have made an asp.net site.

For error handling, e.g. when a user enters a string value into a textBox expecting an integer, on the changed event, if it is an incorrect value I have handled it like -

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "showMyMessage", "ShowMessage('Incorrect value');", true);
```

using -

```
<script>
function ShowMessage(message) { alert(message); }
</script>
```

This works fine, however when the script is fired, the background i.e. the web site itself, is changing shape. In that the navigation bar is going form a horizontal layout to a vertical, and when the users pushes ok on the pop-up, the screen goes back to its original layout.

So the error box is working fine, however the background looks terrible to the user as the site changes layout for a few seconds.

How can I handle errors without the main site altering shape?

**Edit**

I cant add screen shots due to privacy, however it is the orientation of the navigation bar that is changing from horizontal to vertical (when pop up loads) and then back to horizontal once the pop up is closed.

Comment: can you put the html and css of your popup.

Comment: What is the implementation of `ShowMessage()` ?

Comment: Added JavaScript see edit.

Comment: Impossible to help without seeing a working example of this problem I think.

Comment: ill add screenshots of what is actually happening as this is relatively hard to describe.